# Rails and Apartment - Redirect after creating the tenant

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, apartment-gem

I have a Domain model for creating the tenant.

```
class Domain < ApplicationRecord
 after_create :create_tenant
 def create_tenant 
  Apartment::Tenant.create(name) 
 end
end
```

After creating the tenant "example" i want to redirect my browser automatically to http://example.lvh.me:3000

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was easy than I thought .
Simply redirect to the url with your subdomain name after successful tenant creation.
The modifying the create definition in domain controller

```
def create
@domain = Domain.new(domain_params)


respond_to do |format|
  if @domain.save
    format.html { redirect_to "http://#{@domain.name}.lvh.me:3000/users/sign_in", notice: 'Domain was successfully created.' }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @domain.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end
```

Added this line

```
redirect_to "http://#{@domain.name}.lvh.me:3000/users/sign_in"
```

Comment: Is there a more elegant way to do this ?

Answer (score 1):

To redirect to a specific url

`redirect_to user_sign_in_url(subdomain: domain.name)`

Use URL instead of path is the more elegant, rails way to do it.